# println turning up as empty string in go

Tags: arrays, go

So I wrote this small go program, that gives instructions to a turing machine, and prints selected cells from it:

```
    package main

import "fmt"
import s "strings"

func main() {
  fmt.Println(processturing("> > > + + + . ."));
}

func processturing(arguments string) string{
    result := ""
    dial := 0
    cells := make([]int, 30000)
    commands := splitstr(arguments, " ")
    for i := 0;i<len(commands);i++ {
        switch commands[i] {
        case ">":
            dial += 1
        case "<":
            dial -= 1
        case "+":
            cells[dial] += 1
        case "-":
            cells[dial] -= 1
        case ".":
            result += string(cells[dial]) + " "
        }
    }
    return result
}

//splits strings be a delimeter
func splitstr(input, delim string) []string{
    return s.Split(input, delim)
}
```

Problem is, when this is run, the console doesn't display anything. It just displays nothing. How do I make this work to `fmt.println` the resulting string from my function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression

```
 string(cells[dial])
```

yields the UTF-8 representation of the integer value `cells[dial]`. Print the quoted string output to see what's going on:

```
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", processturing("> > > + + + . .")) // prints "\x03 \x03 "
```

I think you want the decimal representation of the integer:

```
 strconv.Itoa(cells[dial])
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/quGCE3wKMj).

Comment: awesome, that fixed the problem.